# Jersey 2.5 not reading jaxb.properties

Tags: jaxb, jersey, moxy

I am trying to get Jersey to use EclipseLink as its context factory, however, the file jaxb.properties is not being read.  The docs say the file needs to be in the folder with the domain classes being mapped and I have verified that.  I'm certain it is not being read because I have fubar'd the class name

javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactoryXXX

Comment: Jersey may fail silently on an incorrect `jaxb.properties` file, so it may still ge read with an invalid entry.  What environment are you running in, and how do you have EclipseLink MOXy on the classpath?

Comment: I'm running on Tomcat 7 with the following dependencies    <dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jaxb.properties.  Add a dependency to "jersey-media-moxy" using Maven.  Jersey will automatically pick up MoxyXmlFeature (contained in the JAR) and then configure and use MoxyContextResolver to build new JAXB instances.

You may need to add an exclusion to the jersey-media-moxy dependency to avoid pulling in an unwanted version of the org.eclipse.persistence.moxy artifact.